# Difficulty showing that: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{(t^2-1)^n}{2^n(t-x)^{n+1}}dt=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\cos\phi)^nd\phi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm having problems with the following integral:
$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{(t^2 - 1)^n}{2^n(t-x)^{n+1}}dt$ where $C$ is any contour around $t=x$.

I know I can choose the contour to be $t = x + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ where $\phi$ goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. Substituting this for $t$ and $dt = i e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1} d\phi$ I have
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{((x + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1})^2 - 1)^n}{2^n(x + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1}-x)^{n+1}} i e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1} d\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{((x + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1})^2 - 1)^n}{2^n(e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1})^{n}}.$$

And for the answer I should get $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi (x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \cos (\phi))^n d\phi$. But I don't really know how to get to the final integral.

Edit:
I tried to expand the numerator and denominator with the binomial expression (since I can see from the final form of the integral that the term $2^n$ vanishes, i.e. it cancels somewhere out) but didn't come really further

Edit2: As FShrike kindly pointed out, I don't need to evaluate the integral, as I started with the Legendre polynomials in the derivative form and have to finish in the integral form. Hence, I only need the step(s) that lead to the final integral form $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi (x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \cos (\phi))^n d\phi$

Comment: Hello again. It’s worth mentioning in your post that you *started* with the Cauchy formula to obtain the Legendre polynomials, and that you’re trying to reverse engineer the integral form of the polynomial. Otherwise some answerers would likely try to evaluate the integral with the basic complex analytic technique that leads you back to the Legendre polynomial, which is not what you want. This is based off our discussion earlier, please correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: @FShrike yes, that is correct. Thank You for the remark! I will add it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ so $(x + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1})^2 - 1=(x+1+e^{i\phi}u)(x-1+e^{i\phi}u)$

But $e^{i\phi}u=(e^{i\phi/2}\sqrt {x+1})(e^{i\phi/2}\sqrt {x-1})$ while $u/\sqrt {x+1}=\sqrt {x-1}$ and the other way around, so forcing the denominator $e^{i\phi}u$ out as above we get that

$$\frac{(x + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1})^2 - 1}{e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}=(e^{-i\phi/2}\sqrt {x+1}+e^{i\phi/2}\sqrt {x-1})(e^{-i\phi/2}\sqrt {x-1}+e^{i\phi/2}\sqrt {x+1})$$

and of course, by multiplying the brackets we get that
$$\frac{(x + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1})^2 - 1}{e^{i\phi}\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}=2x+2\sqrt{x^2 - 1} \cos \phi$$ so taking into account that we divide also by $2$ and then raise to power $n$ gives us the result

(where the last part follows from the obvious fact that) $$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi (x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \cos (\phi))^n d\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi (x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \cos (\phi))^n d\phi$$

Comment: thank you very much!!

Comment: happy to be of help